# Cleaning up the serialization of a closure in Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, serialization, closures, apache-flink

The serialization of anonymous functions (or closures) in Java can often fail because of spurious references to non-serializable objects. For instance, an anonymous class declared within an object formally depends on the object if it is not marked as `static`, even if it does not rely on any method or attribute in the object.

To solve this, many frameworks use closure cleaning utilities:

- in Spark: [ClosureCleaner.scala](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/util/ClosureCleaner.html)
- in Flink: [ClosureCleaner.java](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.9/api/java/org/apache/flink/api/java/ClosureCleaner.html)
- in Chill (copied from Spark): [ClosureCleaner.scala](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/tv.cntt/chill-scala_2.11/latest/com/twitter/chill/ClosureCleaner$.html)

Is there any library to do this, which could be added as a dependency instead of duplicating code as Chill does? Adding Spark or Flink as dependencies to a project just to use their closure cleaners seems a bit much, especially since these classes are not part of the public API. Or is there any reason why these algorithms should not be reused across projects?

Comment: If you downvote this, I would be grateful if you could add a comment to explain why, thanks!